# How to clean solid cedar top guitar?

Tags: guitar, instrument-cleaning

I have [Takamine G330S](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0002E4Z1O) guitar with solid cedar top. What procedure should I use to clean it? I've been using it for 2 years and it has minor spots, mostly from sweat and just general use. No dirt or anything from long term storage like mold, etc.

I have Gibson Pump Polish but I'm afraid that it might stain the cedar wood since it seems to be used for different kind of finish.

Comment: **Hello and welcome to Music.SE!** Can you please give us more information about what happened to the guitar top or why you want to clean it? Thank you.

Comment: Well I've been using it for 2 years and it has minor spots, mostly from sweat and just general use. No dirt or something from long term storage like mold, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Martin too makes a pump polish, and they make cedar-topped guitars, so I suspect that their product would work fine. What you haven't described is the cedar's present finish and condition. I have not compared the Martin and Gibson varieties; for all I know, they could be identical.

For unfinished wood, I often use Lemon Oil -- such as cleaning a fretboard. For ebony boards, no color change would be noticeable. For other materials, a small test patch may be advised to test coloration. I have never noticed any adverse effects from lemon oil. Good luck cleaning up your equipment.

EDIT: after checking Martin's site, they do NOT advise using lemon oil. See http://www.martinguitar.com/guitar-care.html for details.

Comment: Hm, interesting. I guess I'll just use warm soapy water to clean the body.